# Is this bad MVC design?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I wonder if this is bad; having the view know about the controller so it can delegate actions etc  that happens in the view, and have the controller know about the view (this is obviously correct), however it is the bidirectional relationship I wonder if is correct? I want a reference to the controller in the view because I want to delegate all the work to the controller and keep the view clean.

Is this bad design, if so what could I do differently and still achieve the same?

**Controller:**

```
public class Controller {

    private View view;

    public Controller() {
        view = new View(this);
    }

    public void doSomeButtonAction() {
        // More code...
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
public class View implements ActionListener {

    private Controller controller;
    private Button button;

    public View(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;

        // Code for initializing button reference etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        controller.doSomeButtonAction();
    }    
}
```

Comment: That looks exactly like it should.  How can the view *not* know about the controller?

Comment: You could start accessing 'getters' via the 'view' reference in the controller and then attach event listeners etc in the controller. Then the view would now need to have a reference. So, yes the view could live without knowing about the controller.

Comment: Is it a reusable component?  There is nothing inherently "bad" about a view defining at compile time what its buttons actually do, rather than just that they exist and waiting to learn from others at run time what they do.  "This button saves that row of data" is a valid view level specification.  "This button exists and might do something if someone registers a listener" not as helpful :).  Adding in another layer of abstraction for the sake of it just makes everything else that much harder to read!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might come in handy later is to remove the dependency in your `Controller`'s constructor. Pass the view as an argument or use a setter.

```
public class Controller {

    private View view;

    public Controller(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void doSomeButtonAction() {
        // More code...
    }
}
```

This way, your controller is not responsible for creating the `View`. Your program itself (eg. Main) will take care of creating the `View` implementation it requires and inject it when it creates the `Controller`. This will also help with testing if you want to use mock views or controllers.

Your view is responsible for user-program interaction. When it receives some user input it needs to notify some controller, so you must have a reference to it. The `View` should then also have a setter for its `Controller` field. This way you can construct both and pass each other to one another.

Comment: Okey, thanks that is not the answer but it was a good tip though :)

Comment: `Is this bad design, if so what could I do differently and still achieve the same?`

Answer (score 0):

You have the general idea: put logic (the implementation of actionPerformed() to the Controller.  The View would have visible widgets, e.g., your Buttons in a Panel.  And this doesn't look so much like "MVC" to me as "VC", nary a data Model in sight.

There isn't enough code here for me to call it "bad", yet.

Comment: The logic of `actionPerformed()` is in `Controller#doSomeButtonAction()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a MVC design , MVC should separate Model ,View and Controller in layers to get the benefits of the design pattern.

It seems that you are using JSF , so both your View and Controller classes are actually part of View layer in JSF. You would be better of renaming them to something like PageAction, ViewFinder ,ViewFrontController etc.

Comment: A controller should be part of the Presentation (View) layer in 3-layered architecture.

Comment: I agree with that . I am not saying Controller shouldn't be in presentation. It shouldn't mix with your view (page views in webapp) , I understand View class is not a view and actually a presentation class , that's why I suggested to rename it to something more meaningful like  PageAction, ViewFinder ,ViewFrontController etc.

Answer (score 0):

Opinions will vary, however, I like to design the model so as to be the top level client in the application tier, meaning invoked only by the container (app server + any framework) and certainly not by either a view or a model.  For the sake of clarity and cleanliness, I stay away from the view components talking directly to the controller object at the language level, instead make it go through the container via the protocol.  So if a web page needs to provide an additional request to a Java servlet, instead of calling the servlet directly, submit an HTTP (or whatever other protocol) request to the server and let the server route it to the appropriate controller component.  This way, you have an abstraction layer between different components of the MVC, meaning you decouple one from the other and make it easier to replace one component while minimally affecting others if need be.

So my answer would be yes, it is bad for a view to talk back to the controller.  In fact, I like to rely on full [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) in designing MVC whereby no component accesses another directly but have an abstraction layer managed by the container.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning *what* functions a particular button performs is a view-level concern.  The controller is responsible for providing the *how*, but it does not talk upward telling a view what its buttons should do.  It is fine for the view to "know" that "this is a button that invokes the save operation."  The entire purpose of the view is to convert human input into software operations!

If you want re-usable components you can certainly add another layer of abstraction in there, but the code that assigns what operation a button performs is still conceptually part of the 'View' regardless of where you paste it in.